# Tooltip not displaying and no errors logging

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to bind a tooltip using point to layer. No errors are logging to the console and I'm not getting the expected behavior of the tooltip displaying on my stores marker. Anything in the code below jump out at you?

```
      var storesLayer = L.geoJson(stores, {
      pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        return L.circleMarker(latlng);
      },
      style: function (feature) {
        return {
          color: false,
          fillColor: '#083359',
          fillOpacity: '1',
          radius: 10
        }


   var popup = `${feature.STORE_NAME}`
     layer.bindToolTip(popup);
      }
      }).addTo(map);
      //console.log(feature.properties.STORE_NAME);
     // var popup = `${feature.properties.STORE_NAME}`
     // latLng.bindPopup(popup)

    // change opacity of store features outside of 1km to .1
    map.on('click', function (e) {
      storesLayer.eachLayer(function (layer) {
        var distance = e.latlng.distanceTo(layer.getLatLng()) / 1000;

        if (distance > 1) {
          layer.setStyle({
            stroke: false,
            fillOpacity: .1
          });
        } else {
          layer.setStyle({
            fill: true
          });
        }
      });
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I needed to add the onEachFeature option:

```
      var storesLayer = L.geoJson(stores, {
        pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
          return L.circleMarker(latlng);
        },
        style: function (feature) {
          return {
            color: false,
            fillColor: '#083359',
            fillOpacity: '1',
            radius: 10
          }
        },


        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
          layer.bindTooltip(`<h3>${feature.properties.STORE_NAME}</h3>`);
        }
      }).addTo(map);
```